# SQL creating table difficulty

Tags: mysql, sql

When trying to create a table in SQL it gives me a syntax error, and I'm not sure what is the problem, since it's a very simple table

I tried this...

```sql
CREATE TABLE happy (
    rank INT,
    swag VARCHAR(20)
);
```

which is the typical syntax to create a table

I tried to remove primary key, but I was getting the same thing.

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Also, show the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

> The rank is a MySQL reserved word defined in MySQL version 8.0.

Try some other column name than `rank`